# detect multiple clicks on a banner using user information

Tags: php, click, banner-ads

I'm preparing with my small company a new PHP project about **Exchange Announcements**

The users can add banners from the control panel also they can copy a code and put it in the body of their pages **Like Google Adsense**, if a visitor click on user 1 banner, the user winning points and the owner of the banner discount points

***All is ok :)***

My question is about how to detect if the same visitor click on banners (To cheat and win points), now we use IP to detect the same clicks but I know it isn't good way to detecting

Thanks in advance

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Please don't go out of the subject

Comment: Thanks, I will read the discussion

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your IP method with saving a cookie in users browser too for that banner. So the next time you see the cookie and know that user has already clicked this banner.

To get a better result from IP method too, combine it with time, allow multiple clicks from same IP but don't allow multiple clicks from same IP in a small time period.

So you block all those who have the cookie set and all those IPs who have a click saved in last, say 5 minutes ...

Comment: I thought in this way :) Thank you